# .NET Core project is getting error while using CouchbaseNetClient 3.0.0 package

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, couchbase

I've been trying to develop a webclient with dotnetcore(v3) on mac os x which can inject json formatted values into couchbase that lives in a docker container( at least for now). So after i installed couchbase .net core sdk version 3.0.0 and Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection nuget packages, in my project folder at `Startup.cs` file i've been getting this same error.

`Reference to type 'CouchbaseClientDefinition' claims it is defined in 'Couchbase.NetClient', but it could not be found (CS7069)`

It is a new project so for now there is no developed code in other files either.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection does not work (yet) with Couchbase .NET SDK 3.0. You could try it with 2.x and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm--I'm getting the same error on Windows. I opened an issue on the repository: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase.Extensions/issues/70

Comment: Other versions below 3.0.0 are ok as you said. Thank you for your response i will follow the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading v3.0.1 problem has resolved.